# Trying to construct a like-selecting MySQL query fails

Tags: mysql, voting-system

## Background info

### System

OS:

```
bash$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.5
Codename:       squeeze
```

MySQL:

```
bash$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1
```

### Database

Engine: `MyISAM`

Table: post_votes

```
mysql> describe post_votes;
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| post_uuid | binary(16)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_uuid | binary(16)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| vote      | tinyint(4)          | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table: posts

```
mysql> describe posts;
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id          | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
| post_uuid   | binary(16)          | YES  | UNI | NULL                 |                |
| owner_uuid  | binary(16)          | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| created     | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| edited      | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| title       | varchar(50)         | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| description | varchar(150)        | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| link        | varchar(100)        | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| properties  | varchar(20)         | YES  |     | 00000000000000000000 |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## The Problem

I want to select posts depending on their upvote/downvote ratio. I've come up with a query that counts upvotes and downvotes but can't seem to join it to the actual posts.

### The working (uncomplete) query

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(*), post_uuid, 'upvotes' AS 'mode'
    FROM post_votes a
    WHERE a.vote = 1
    GROUP BY post_uuid
)
UNION
(
    SELECT COUNT(*), post_uuid, 'downvotes' AS 'mode'
    FROM post_votes a
    WHERE a.vote = -1
    GROUP BY post_uuid
)
```

### The broken query

```
(
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*), post_uuid, 'upvotes' AS 'mode'
        FROM post_votes a
        WHERE a.vote = 1
        GROUP BY post_uuid
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*), post_uuid, 'downvotes' AS 'mode'
        FROM post_votes a
        WHERE a.vote = -1
        GROUP BY post_uuid
    )
)
a
LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.post_uuid = b.post_uuid
```

What am I doing wrong? the error message I get is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
(
SELECT COUNT(*), post_uuid, 'downvotes' AS 'mode'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UNION` pair is effectively a derived table and must appear in a `FROM` clause to participate in the `JOIN`. Since it is in the `FROM` clause now, you must `SELECT` its columns, otherwise your query has no `SELECT` clause at all. MySQL's syntax is lenient, but not so lenient as to permit a missing `SELECT` clause.

```
/* SELECT the cols produced by the UNION */
SELECT 
   a.`num`, 
   a.`post_uuid`,
   a.`mode`,
  /* And other columns from `posts` if needed */
   b.`something`,
   b.`something_else`,
   b.`some_other_thing`
/* UNIONs are a derived table, belonging in FROM */
FROM (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as num, post_uuid, 'upvotes' AS 'mode'
        FROM post_votes a
        WHERE a.vote = 1
        GROUP BY post_uuid
    )
    UNION
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) num, post_uuid, 'downvotes' AS 'mode'
        FROM post_votes a
        WHERE a.vote = 1
        GROUP BY post_uuid
    )
) a
LEFT JOIN posts b ON a.post_uuid = b.post_uuid
```

Looking over this, I believe you can simplify away the `UNION` by using a `SUM(CASE)` aggregate pattern:

```
SELECT 
  b.post_uuid,
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.vote = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS upvotes,
  /* Assume -1 for downvotes? */
  SUM(CASE WHEN a.vote = -1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS downvotes
FROM
  posts b
  LEFT JOIN post_votes a ON a.post_uuid = b.post_uuid
GROUP BY b.post_uuid
```

Comment: Thank you, that works very well! Also very good explanation! Have any ideas on how I could make the `mode` variable the title for the `COUNT(*)`? because simply doing `COUNT(*) as 'upvotes'` throws a big fat error at my face

Comment: `COUNT(*) AS upvotes` should work fine, however once you `UNION` them together, it would be hard to keep track of which is which and without `UNION ALL`, you might lose some rows.  I aliased the `COUNT()` as `num` above.

Comment: If you post what error you got when trying to alias `upvotes` I might be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: Seems like I can't reproduce the error, but rather I'm losing either up or downvote.

Comment: @Akke Well anyway, look over the bit I just added, because I think it solves the whole thing without the `UNION`.  In your query you have `a.vote = 1` for both up and down, but should down be `-1`?

Comment: Getting an error here: SQL ERROR (1052): Column 'post_uuid' in field list is ambiguous.

Comment: @Micael: `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the `b.post_uuid` (not the `a.`)

Comment: Seems to be working great, I do however get a null row in the beginning

Comment: @ypercube Yep, I switched around the sides of the join and missed fixing the group by.

Comment: @Akke Change the select to `b.post_uuid` and you should not get a NULL row.

Comment: One more quick question. How do I refer to the selected cols "upvotes" and "downvotes" when trying to select upvotes-downvotes as rank?

Comment: @Akke in the same query you would have to use the full calculations, but you can wrap the whole thing in a subquery and the upvotes and downvotes names can be used.